# How to check the response or status code in angular 8 for upload file to S3 Presigned URL and statusCode is 200

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, angular8

Request to upload file:

```
// upload file to the pre-signed url
const httpOptions = {
 headers: new HttpHeaders({
 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=' + file.name + '',
 observe: 'response'
 })
};

this.httpClient.put(preSingedUrl, file, httpOptions)
.subscribe((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
console.log(response); // it's returning null
});
```

response is always getting null, but in the network tab status is 200 OK.

```
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 1207
content-type: application/json
date: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 07:38:06 GMT
status: 200
strict-transport-security: 'max-age=31536000'
x-amz-apigw-id: someid
x-amzn-requestid: someid
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=someid;Sampled=1
```

How to read the status 200 OK using angular 8.

Comment: From this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56749149/how-to-check-the-response-or-status-code-in-angular-8-for-upload-file-to-s3-pres, 200 is correct and the file url already included in your put url. So before sent the request, you should already know the expected saved file url.

Comment: @raykin my question is regarding how to read the response or check the status of the request to upload file to this Url is 200 ok.

Comment: Hi @JayotiParkash. You have passed the httpOptions. Could you also add what have you passed in it ?

Comment: Edit and update your question with the code for it

Comment: @Gurpreet_Carmel_5 I updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in **httpOptions**, which is why you are getting response null.

If you are trying to use **observe: 'response'** to get the response back in subscribe, you are passing it incorrectly as a **header**.

It should be passed as a property of httpOptions.

To confirm the same, in the image below, the implementation of **httpClient.put()** in 
the type file **http.d.ts** in the package **@angular/common** can be seen, where **observe** is a property.

[image: Code for httpClient.put]

Additionally, in the type file **http.d.ts** the type of observe is a string literal type.
(More on string literal types here : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).

So **observe** in **httpOptions** needs to be cast to this type.

So change this:

```
// upload file to the pre-signed url
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=' + file.name + '',
     observe: 'response'
  })
};
```

To this :

```
// Custom type for casting
type bodyType = 'body';

// upload file to the pre-signed url
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=' + file.name + '',
  }),
  observe: <bodyType>'response'
};
```