# content-type header missing in angular service call

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm using **Angular 8** and **Django API**. I have an endpoint which returns **zip** file directly.

I tested the endpoint with **Postman** and everything is working fine and the response header of postman is

[image]

With the same payload data, the Angular is not having proper response header

[image]

**Content-Type** is missing and **Content-Length** is 0.

The angular service is

```
public download(data: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${environment.apiURL}${this.endpoint}download/`;

    return this.http.post(url, data, {responseType: 'blob'});
}
```

and controller

```
private download(payload) {
    this.service.download({data: payload}).subscribe(res => {

      console.log('res: ', res);  // This consoles Blob {size: 0, type: 'text/xml'}

      const b = new Blob([res], {
        type: 'application/zip'
      });
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(b);
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'qrcodes.zip';
      a.click();

    }, error => {
      console.log('Error downloading multiple files: ', error);
    });
  }
```

**Is the issue related to backend (It's working in Postman with same payload) or something missing in Angular?**

Comment: You're calling the `this.service.download` method on the service but have shown us the code for `multiDownload` in your service, is that just a typo while pasting code here?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. Updated question

Comment: yes, this  issue related to backend API call. you need to allow that for the post request to expose the header's.

Comment: But same is working with Postman.

Comment: I just posted the link below where I faced the same issue, have a look.

Comment: Did you added the header? You can Angular interceptors to add headers more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same issue using angular 8 and got a response for the same here:

[How to check the response or status code in angular 8 for upload file to S3 Presigned URL and statusCode is 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56749149/how-to-check-the-response-or-status-code-in-angular-8-for-upload-file-to-s3-pres)

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Once try with below code by passing http headers, might be it will work:

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'responseType': 'blob',
    // 'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};

public multiDownload(data: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${environment.apiURL}${this.endpoint}download/`;
    return this.http.post(url, data, httpOptions);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Best way to handle is implementing HTTP interceptor which will intercept every Webservice calls and add Auth token.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor( {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `${auth-token}`
                }
            });
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not related to `Authorization` header. Interceptor is already there and `Authorization` header is going through as well.